# How to index files with Elasticsearch, Ingest-Mapper and NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

actually I am trying to index some files (most important PDFs) with Elasticsearch and NEST client from ASP.net Core 1.0.

I found some code snippets and tried to use it for my purpose.

Those are the code segments that I use to set up the Elasticsearch index and the Pipeline:

```
    private void SetupElasticSearch()
    {
        ConnectionSettings settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(_appSettings.ElasticSearchSettings.Url))
           .MapDefaultTypeIndices(m => m
           .Add(typeof(FSDocumentFile), _appSettings.ElasticSearchSettings.IndexName)

       ).OnRequestCompleted(response =>
       {
           _logger.LogInformation(String.Format("{0} {1}", response.HttpMethod, response.Uri));

           if (response.RequestBodyInBytes != null)
           {
               _logger.LogInformation(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.RequestBodyInBytes));
           }

           // log out the response and the response body, if one exists for the type of response
           _logger.LogInformation(String.Format("{0}", response.HttpStatusCode));
           if (response.ResponseBodyInBytes != null)
           {
               _logger.LogInformation(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.ResponseBodyInBytes));
           }
       });

        ElasticClient client = new ElasticClient(settings);

        CreateElasticSearchIndex(client);
        CreatePipeline(client);
    }

    private void CreateElasticSearchIndex(ElasticClient Client)
    {

        Client.DeleteIndex(_appSettings.ElasticSearchSettings.IndexName);

        Client.CreateIndex(_appSettings.ElasticSearchSettings.IndexName, c => c
            .Settings(s => s
                .Analysis(a => a
                    .Analyzers(ad => ad
                        .Custom("windows_path_hierarchy_analyzer", ca => ca
                            .Tokenizer("windows_path_hierarchy_tokenizer")
                        )
                    )
                .Tokenizers(t => t
                    .PathHierarchy("windows_path_hierarchy_tokenizer", ph => ph
                        .Delimiter('\\')
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<FSDocumentFile>(mp => mp
                .AllField(all => all
                    .Enabled(false)
                )
                .Properties(ps => ps
                    .Number(n => n
                        .Name(nn => nn.Id)
                    )
                    .Text(s => s
                        .Name(n => n.Comment)
                        //.Analyzer("windows_path_hierarchy_analyzer")
                    )
                    //.Text(s => s
                    //    .Name(n => n.Content)
                    //)
                    .Object<Attachment>(a => a
                        .Name(n => n.FileData)
                            .Properties(p => p
                                .Text(t => t
                                    .Name(n => n.Name)
                                )
                                .Text(t => t
                                  .Name(n => n.Content)
                                )
                                .Text(t => t
                                  .Name(n => n.ContentType)
                                )
                                .Number(n => n
                                  .Name(nn => nn.ContentLength)
                                )
                                .Date(d => d
                                  .Name(n => n.Date)
                                )
                                .Text(t => t
                                  .Name(n => n.Author)
                                )
                                .Text(t => t
                                  .Name(n => n.Title)
                                )
                                .Text(t => t
                                  .Name(n => n.Keywords)
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );
    }

    private void CreatePipeline(ElasticClient Client)
    {
        Client.PutPipeline("attachments", p => p
          .Description("Document attachment pipeline")
          .Processors(pr => pr
            .Attachment<FSDocumentFile>(a => a
              .Field(f => f.FileData.Content)
              .TargetField(f => f.Content)
            )
            .Remove<FSDocumentFile>(r => r
              .Field(f => f.FileData)
            )
          )
        );
    }
```

This is the definition of the the FSFileInfo classe that is used for indexing:

```
[ElasticsearchType(Name = "FSDocumentFile")]
public class FSDocumentFile
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// FileData Base64 encoded
    /// </summary>

    public string Content { get; set; }

    [Attachment(Store = true)]
    public Attachment FileData { get; set; }

    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

This is the code that I use to index the file:

```
        FSDocumentFile fsFile = new FSDocumentFile()
        {
            Id = df.DocumentFileID,
            FileData = new Attachment()
            {
                Content = Convert.ToBase64String(fd.FileBytes),
                ContentType = "application/pdf",
                ContentLength = fd.FileBytes.Count(),
                Name = fileName
            },
            Comment = "TEst Comment" + df.DocumentFileID.ToString()
        };

        ElasticClient client = new ElasticClient(settings);

        Result callResult = client.Index<FSDocumentFile>(fsFile, fi => fi.Pipeline("attachments")).Result;
```

It always results in an error on Elasticsearch that says:

> [2016-11-28T15:40:28,311][ERROR][o.e.a.i.IngestActionFilter] [mU3hlQ7] failed to execute pipeline [attachments]
>   org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ElasticsearchParseException[Error parsing document in field [fileData.content]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[field [c
>   ontent] not present as part of path [fileData.content]];
>           at org.elasticsearch.ingest.CompoundProcessor.newCompoundProcessorException(CompoundProcessor.java:156) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.0-rc1.jar:5.0.0-rc1]
>           at org.elasticsearch.ingest.CompoundProcessor.execute(CompoundProcessor.java:107) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.0-rc1.jar:5.0.0-rc1]
>           at org.elasticsearch.ingest.Pipeline.execute(Pipeline.java:58) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.0-rc1.jar:5.0.0-rc1]
>           at org.elasticsearch.ingest.PipelineExecutionService.innerExecute(PipelineExecutionService.java:166) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.0-rc1.jar:5.0.0-rc1]
>           at org.elasticsearch.ingest.PipelineExecutionService.access$000(PipelineExecutionService.java:41) ~[elasticsearch-5.0.0-rc1.jar:5.0.0-rc1]
>           at org.elasticsearch.ingest.PipelineExecutionService$1.doRun(PipelineExecutionService.java:65) [elasticsearch-5.0.0-rc1.jar:5.0.0-rc1]
>           at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:504) [elasticsearch-5.0.0-rc1.jar:5.0.0-rc1]
>           at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) [elasticsearch-5.0.0-rc1.jar:5.0.0-rc1]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_112]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_112]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_112]
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ElasticsearchParseException[Error parsing document in field [fileData.content]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[field [content] not present as part of
>   path [fileData.content]];

Can someone please assist me? Or maybe point me to a good tutorial how to use Elasticsearch, Ingest-Mapper and NEST client together?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Did you see the blog post on ingest attachment with .NET? https://www.elastic.co/blog/the-future-of-attachments-for-elasticsearch-and-dotnet

Comment: Thanks. That helped me perfectly. I got it now up and running. I was using the Pipeline in a wrong way.

Comment: No problem,happy to help :)